# Mongoose - Add bulk and retrieve count of added and dups removed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a query for create or save i can use that would also return an output on how many added and how many skipped?

I'm trying to get an output like :

> Tried 185,000 rows - Added : 100,000 - Skipped 85,000 dups - All done!

Here is my code

```
let db = require('../models/db');    
fs.readFile(localfile, 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
    let ResultArray = [];
    let FileData = contents.split("\n");
    let dupCount= 0;
    let addCount= 0;
        FileData.forEach(datum => {
            db.findOne({weburl: datum}, function(err){
                if (err){
                    ResultArray.push({
                    weburl: datum,
                    status: "New"
                    });
                    addCount++;
                }
                else {
                    dupCount++;
                }
            });
        });
            console.log('Duplicates Found : ' + dupCount);
            console.log('Entries Added : ' + addCount);
            console.log(ResultArray);
            console.log("Try to add to DB vvvvvvvvv");

    db.create(ResultArray, function(err,docs){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log("DB Updated Successfully!!!!!!")
        }
    });
```

I tried to use a counter while building the Array, this way i never add a dup and i can also catch it and +1 the dup counter

the counter always says 0

Comment: Could you be more specific? Yes this sort of information is available from `bulkWrite()` responses. Yes, it does depend on how you use it. Yes you would need to deduce some of the math yourself, i.e count which of the "exceptions" are actually related to duplicate failures. A question is generally expected to have you "show what you tried" as well. If nothing else, it gives context to what you are asking.

Comment: @NeilLunn Added my code and what ive tried so far

Comment: What is `db`? This is using mongoose is it not? Is this just supposed to be a "one off" script to load some data? If so, then you're probably better off with just the plain driver than using mongoose for this. To do what I think you want should be able to be done in less lines of code than you have here, and a lot more efficiently.

Comment: updated code to show what db is, its not a one off really, this is a core part of the whole that im making and it requires me to read files and keep adding to the database and then retreving the dup count and insert count

Comment: mongoose isnt really necessary i just learned all of this with mongoose and never tried without, i could give it a shot